# &quot; is auto converting to " through Document & Transformer API

Tags: java, dom, java-8, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am loading xml file (pom.xml) through `org.w3c.dom.Document` and editing some node's value (basically changing the version value of some dependency) through `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`
& `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource`.

But problem is that, this also convert all occurrence of `&quot;` to **"** character, which I don't want. See below sample:

```
<Export-Package>!${bundle.namespace}.internal.*,${bundle.namespace}.*;version=&quot;${project.version}&quot;</Export-Package>
```

converted to:

```
<Export-Package>!${bundle.namespace}.internal.*,${bundle.namespace}.*;version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
```

Please help on this, how I can ignore these auto conversion with currently consumed API.

Code Sample:

```
public void writeDocument(File filePath)
{
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    this.thisDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Transformer transformer;
    try
    {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(thisDoc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(filePath);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
    catch (TransformerException e)
    {
        VersionUpdateExceptions.throwException(e, LOG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: We are working on some utility for version upgrade, and don't want any unrelated changes except the version upgrade.

Comment: But this would only happen once; after this conversion happened, all subsequent updates would make the intended minimal changes.

Comment: could you post the code that does the update?

Comment: Code sample added.

Answer (score 1):

This is the required behavior by the [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Load and Save Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-LS-20040407/DOM3-LS.html):

> Within the character data of a document (outside of markup), any
> characters that cannot be represented directly are replaced with
> character references. Occurrences of '<' and '&' are replaced by the
> predefined entities < and &. **The other predefined entities
> (>, ', and ") might not be used**, except where needed
> (e.g. using > in cases such as ']]>').

For example, if you use `&quot;` inside an attribute:

```
<Export-Package id="&quot;test&quot;">
```

`&quot;` will be preserved. Otherwise, it won't.

If absolutely necessary you could achieve the preserving of """ with an ugly hack.

- Read the `pom.xml` as a `String` and replace ocurrences of `&quot;` by some "marker" string
- To parse the document use an `StringReader` to create an `InputSource`
- Execute your method, but creating a `StreamResult` with a `StringWriter`.
- Get the content from the `StringWriter` as a `String` and replace your marker string with `&quot;`
- Save the content to the file

Comment: cannot go with suggested approach "&quot;test&quot;", just looking how I can ignore this replacement without making any changes in source pom.xml. Any ways thanks for detailing this.